# Unable to resolve runtime errors after upgrading .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8, .net-4.7.2

I recently changed the target framework of my Cloud Service to .NET 4.8 from .NET 4.7.2. However after doing so, I have received a lot of errors.
Listing a few errors here:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

> Cannot define a new extension method because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference to System.Core.dll?

> The type or namespace name 'IEnumerable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> 'ContentServerConfiguration.AllowedUnauthenticatedPathPrefixes' in explicit interface declaration is not found among members of the interface that can be implemented

> Predefined type 'System.Int32', 'System.Object', 'System.String', 'System.Linq'  is not defined or imported

1. For resolving `Predefined type System.String, System.Void and System.Object not defined or imported` error, I tried deleting all the **bin**, **obj** and **.vs** folders. Ran the **dotnet restore** command which showed "there is nothing to restore" and restarted the solution. *However the errors pertained*.
2. I also tried to add references again to project. It then showed a pop-up that "mscorlib" and "System.Core" are automatically referenced by the build system.
3. I also tried to add the necessary assemblies like this:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel" culture="neutral"   publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

However the error still pertained post rebuilding.

4. I event tried adding the below code in Web.Config file of the project:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Didn't provide any resolution.

5. I **unloaded** and then **loaded the project with dependencies**, still, didn't make any change.

Really need help as to what should be actually done to resolve the errors I am facing post upgrading to .NET framework v4.8, given that downgrading back to v4.7.2 is not an option.